# What is the name for the complement of accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, accuracy, definition

I have a metric that is defined as $1 - Accuracy$ and I need a name for it. Is there a scientific name for the complement of accuracy?

Comment: Seems as if there may be [more than one definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision)  for *accuracy* in common usage. Which do you mean?

Comment: I mean specifically accuracy. I have a metric that is defined in academics as blah_blah_accuracy and I can only compute 1-X of that metric. So, I was curious for the definition of the inverse of accuracy to call my metric blah_blah_(inverse of accuracy)

Comment: I don't mean to be a stickler, but what you're describing here isn't an 'inverse', it's a 'complement' (or, _a_ particular type of complement if you're going down proper fuzzy theory, albeit 1-a is the commonest version used and the one typically implied unless explicitly specified otherwise). In fact, 'the complement of the accuracy' is a perfectly valid description for it and could be notated as $A^c$ (if accuracy is notated as $A$).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou is right. You are looking for the complement, so long as $A$, and thus $A^c$ or $\bar{A}$ is restricted to $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Right, I will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen people use $\text{error rate} = 1 - \text{accuracy}$, on the premise that accuracy is the proportion of samples classified correctly, so the error rate is the proportion of samples classified *incorrectly*.

Answer (score 2):

[image] would be my guess but that's just me  ...................!

Comment: It's about name of the meric, not English language.

Comment: @Tim I beg to differ: the question seems to be *only* about English.  This answer by IrishStat needed to be posted if only to point out its obviousness (+1).